# Jetty http client enforces WWW-Auhenticate

Tags: java, scala, http, jetty

I'm using JettyHttp Client to call external API code below:

```
object Test extends App {

  val client = new HttpClient(new SslContextFactory.Client())
  client.start()
  val response = client.POST("https://xxx")
    .header("authorization","bearer LOL")
    .content(new StringContentProvider("{}"))
    .send()

  println("xd")

}
```

and the result is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpResponseException: HTTP protocol violation: Authentication challenge without WWW-Authenticate header
```

this is fine - works like described here - https://web.archive.org/web/20191231154352/http://www.eclipse.org:80/jetty/documentation/current/http-client-authentication.html

But I also tried this:

```
object Test extends App {

  val client = new HttpClient(new SslContextFactory.Client())
  client.getAuthenticationStore.addAuthenticationResult(new Authentication.Result {
    override def getURI: URI = URI.create("https://xxx")
    override def apply(request: Request): Unit = request.header("authorization", "bearer lol")
  })
  client.start()
  val response = client.POST("https://xxx")
    .content(new StringContentProvider("{}"))
    .send()

  println("xd")

}
```

and still the same result. I cannot enforce the external server to return proper WWW-Authenticate header in response with 401. Can I make the Jetty client somehow to send just the request with Authorization header without this first 401 request?
The external API works fine - I can curl the API and get the proper answer.

Comment: What happens if you use real values, and use the API properly (without overriding methods)? `client.getAuthenticationStore.addAuthenticationResult(new Authentication.Result(URI.create("https://xxx", "userfoo", "pass")))`.  That "bearer lol" doesn't match any known authorization algorithm and the server is 100% correct in rejecting it and asking for the auth again.

Comment: That was nothing wrong with the Jetty Client. It was an unlucky coincidence. I forgot about changing the token, so the server response was 401 and Jetty instead of telling me that token was wrong and the response was 401 - returned that WWW-Authenticate header is not present. 

I found it using the Wireshark and see whole communication so if you found similar issue just check every single request you send to server. Thanks! :)